# VBA get connector 'from shape' and 'to shape'

Tags: vba

I have a flow design in Excel (using shapes, connectors, etc).
What I need is to have a matrix and for every shape to have all the predecessors and all the successors. 
In VBA, to do that I'm trying to do something like:
- I'm listing all the connectors (Shapes.AutoShapeType = -2) 
- for each one I want to have the name of the shape 'from' and the name of the shape 'to'.

I hope you get the idea.
I don't find the properties of the connector in order to retrieve this info.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub getTransitions()
    ''the sheet with the design
    Set designSheet = Sheets("DesignSheet")
    Set tempSheet = Sheets("temp") 'Sheets.Add

    lLoop = 0

    'Loop through all shapes on active sheet
    For Each sShapes In designSheet.Shapes

        'Increment Variable lLoop for row numbers
        With sShapes

           ''connector shape type
           If ((sShapes.AutoShapeType) = -2) Then
                lLoop = lLoop + 1
                tempSheet.Cells(lLoop + 1, 1) = sShapes.Name
                tempSheet.Cells(lLoop + 1, 2) = sShapes.AutoShapeType

               ''here I want to have for the sShapes the from shape and the to shape


            End If



        End With

     Next sShapes
End Sub
```

Does anyone know the shape parameters for having this info ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that utilizing [the `ConnectorFormat` object returned by the `ConnectorFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221843%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and looking into the [`BeginConnectedShape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa217374%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and [`EndConnectedShape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa205855%28v=office.10%29.aspx) properties may be your best bet.

Comment: Yes, I just find it my self also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
Set g = ActiveSheet
i = 1
For Each s In g.Shapes
    If ((s.AutoShapeType) <> -2) Then 'all shapes without connectors
        c = 0
        For Each s1 In g.Shapes
            If ((s1.AutoShapeType) = -2) Then 'only connectors
                With s1.ConnectorFormat
                   Set a = .BeginConnectedShape
                   Set b = .EndConnectedShape
                End With
                If a.Name = s.Name Or b.Name = s.Name Then
                    c = c + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next s1

        g.Cells(i, "A").Value = s.Name 'name of shape 
        g.Cells(i, "B").Value = c 'count of connectors

    i = i + 1
    End If
Next s
```