# Make a connector line invisible VB when textbox is

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm working on an PowerPoint presentation with Visual Basic.
I have a ComboBox with different alternatives, when I choose an alternative, TextBox1 shows, otherwise TextBox1 is invisible, which works correctly with this code:

```vb
If ComboBox1.text = "hello" Then 
    TextBox1.Visible = True
Else 
    TextBox1.Visible = False
```

My problem is that in the PowerPoint there are connector lines, but these won't hide with TextBox (see attached picture). Please help, how do I make the connector show and hide based on the code.

[image]

Comment: Enumerate `Connector` shapes on the slide. See which of them have the textbox shape [as its `BeginConnectedShape` or `EndConnectedShape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651285/11683). Make those `Connector`s' shapes `Visible` property equal to the textbox'es.

Comment: @GSerg please help, I don't understand what you mean, can you give an example in code?

Comment: Enumerate means to loop through all the shapes on the slide and find the one you need to hide it. If you know the name already and the name is consistent then you can hide it by name. You can also group the text box and the connector and then hide the group by name as well.